# Change app title dynamically in UWP

Tags: uwp, filenames, titlebar

I'm currently building an app that starts recording the screen at some point using Windows Game DVR. That recorder takes the app name as file name when it's done recording.
I found out how to change the app title using Applicationview.GetForCurrentView(); and it does change the title of the window of my app. However, it doesn't take this title into the filename after recording. 
When I record something like a Word document or my Visual Studio Project, it does show the specific name in the filename, so there must be another level where the name needs to be changed. 
Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8024eafe-3969-4d41-bb56-85a1dd01a2ae/uwp-how-to-change-display-name-after-app-installed?forum=wpdevelop) you cannot do that.

It seems that Xbox DVR gets the name of the installed app and that cannot be changed at runtime.
For changing the app title you need to first uninstall the app, modify Package.appxmanifest and then install the app.

What about a little workaround here. You know your app name when it is installed and you know where Xbox DVR saves video file recordings. You can write a file system watcher that will sense new files in that directory and rename those to your needs.

Comment: The name is already changed before the recording starts. The app starts off as "Appname", then I add something to make it "Subject- Appname", and after that, i start the recording, which gets saved as "Appname - <timestamp>"

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand it correctly from your post. Only I can confirm that I experience the same behavior. Maybe a tryout but: App title is defined in Package.appxmanifest (Display name). Is there any possibility to change it there at the runtime?

Comment: I take a deeper look how to change UWP app name at runtime and I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but couldn't find any fixes. Even tried changing the value via Brackets to make it a get; set; (its read only in VS), but it changed back to get; as soon as it restarted.

Comment: About your workaround, that does sound very good. I'll look into that! Thanks!!